# Converting fft code from Matlab to C#

Tags: c#, matlab, signal-processing, fft

im using LomontFFT algorith for C#. Code in Matlab is as follows:

```
idx = 3000 : 5048;
figure      
hold on
plot(abs(fft(a_eeg1_raw(idx))), 'y')
%Title,xlabel,ylabel etc
```

So I tried my best to do exactly the same in C#:

```
int idx_start = 3000 + 1;
int idx_end = 5048;
LomontFFT my_fft = new LomontFFT();
double[] temp = new double[idx_end - idx_start + 1];
for (int i = idx_start, j = 0; i < idx_end + 1; i++, j++)
   temp[j] = a_eeg1_raw[i];
my_fft.RealFFT(temp, true); // With (A,B) (1,-1) - signal processing
for (int i = 3, j = 1; i < temp.Count() - 1; i = i + 2, j++) // as long as first to entries have only real parts I'm starting from 3rd entry (imaginary part)
   series_a_eeg1_fft.Points.Add(new DataPoint(Convert.ToDouble(j), Math.Abs(temp[i])));
for (int i = temp.Count() - 1, j = seria_a_eeg1_raw.Points.Count() - 1; i > 2; i = i - 2, j++)
   series_a_eeg1_fft.Points.Add(new DataPoint(Convert.ToDouble(j), Math.Abs(temp[i])));
model_tab1.PlotModel.Series.Add(series_a_eeg1_fft);
```

The values that I've got from this code are much different than those in Matlab. Shape of Plot is not so much different anyway its not the same. I'm pretty sure that I forgot about something important, but after 3 hrs of staring at this code I cant find what is wrong. Could someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`abs(fft(x))` is not the same as `abs(real(fft(x)))`.  You aren't properly combining the real and imaginary parts.

Assuming [this is the documentation](http://www.lomont.org/Software/Misc/FFT/LomontFFT.html):

> Compute the forward or inverse Fourier Transform of data, with
>   data containing real valued data only. **The output is complex
>
>   valued after the first two entries, stored in alternating real
>
>   and imaginary parts**. The first two returned entries are the real
>   parts of the first and last value from the conjugate symmetric
>   output, which are necessarily real

Comment: Thanks, that solve my problem pretty well, right know im reading about abs in matlab.

Comment: @Finchsize: `abs` of a complex number is just Pythagorean theorem: `sqrt(real*real + imaginary*imaginary)`